# Using user input to search through a dictionary of various data-types?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to take user input and check if it is in a dictionary.
The user is expected to input strings, floats and ints but only strings are comparing properly.

searching for '5' returns works but neither 10 nor 15.0 do as the input is being converted to a string.

other than implementing a check to see force the user to nominate what type of data they are searching for is there a way to do this?

```py
new_dict = {'a': '5', 'b':10, 'c':15.0}
do_something = False
search_term = input('enter term: ')
print(search_term)
print(type(search_term))
for k,v in new_dict.items():
    print(v)
    if v == search_term:
        do_something = True
        print ('yes')

print(do_something)
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `input` in Python 3 always returns strings. It is up to you to cast them to `int` or `float` or whatever your requirement is. Is there some reason why you can't compare `str(v) == search_term` ?

Comment: this is the one. Spent so long working on one answer that I totally neglected the easiest one. Thanks, again.

Comment: Keep in mind that this method will not be able to differentiate between `'5'` (str) and `5` (int) if both exist as values. It'll match both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do somthing like :

```
new_dict = {'a': '5', 'b':10, 'c':15.0}
do_something = False
search_term = input('enter term: ')
for k,v in new_dict.items():
    if v == int(search_term):
        do_something = True
        print("yes")
    elif v == str(search_term):
        do_something = True
        print ('yes')
```

Comment: `int(seach_term)` would throw a `ValueError` if the input is a non-numerical string, and for floats.

Comment: the code is just to demonstrate  to the OP how to do it, he should using try - except if he wants to

Answer (score 2):

just convert both variables that you are comparing into string:

```
new_dict = {'a': '5', 'b':10, 'c':15.0}
do_something = False
search_term = input('enter term: ')
for k,v in new_dict.items():
    if str(v) == str(search_term):
        do_something = True
        print ('yes')

print(do_something)
```

another solution:

```
new_dict = {'a': '5', 'b':10, 'c':15.0}
do_something = False
search_term = input('enter term: ')
for k,v in new_dict.items():
    try:
        search_term = float(search_term)
        v = float(v)
    except:
        pass
    if v == search_term:
        do_something = True
        print ('yes')

print(do_something)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `if v == search_term:` with `if repr(v) == search_term:` works, it will work on `'5'` as the input, but not on `"5"` as the input.